# How can I add the class name of an object as the index of the serializated json in JMSSerialize

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a simple class like:

```
class Car
{
    public doors;
    public color;
    public seats;
}
```

If I serialize a new object with:

```
$this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($newCar, 'json');
```

I will get something like:

```
{doors:1, color: 'red', seats: 4}
```

I wonder if it's possible to have this instead (Edit: and to be able to deserialize the same string):

```
car:{doors:1, color: 'red', seats: 4}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// Encode
$className = get_class($newCar);
$jmsSerialize = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($newCar, 'json');
$resultJSONEncode = json_encode([$className=>$jmsSerialize]);
var_dump($resultJSONEncode);

// Decode
$resultJSONDecode = json_decode($resultJSONEncode, true);
$jmsDesrialize = $this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($resultJSONDecode[$className], $className, 'json');
var_dump($jmsDesrialize);
```

Comment: Yes, but then I won't be able to deserialize `car:{doors:1, color: 'red', seats: 4}`

Comment: I change my answer, I hope that can help you. :)

Comment: Well +1 because It's a possible solution. I was looking for something cleaner with a configuration or serialization listeners. Thanks :)